# SORM Framework: whereContains

Tags: scala, filter, frameworks, full-text-search, sorm

Is it possible to filter the rows which string-columns contains special substring? Expressions like `.whereContains("name", "Pavel")` throws exception: `Exception: Filter "Contains" is not supported for mapping "String"`. Of course, I can easily use scala filter but DB should do it better, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in `whereContains` the path should refer to some collection, for example if you were searching for a name within a set of nested names of some entity.

What you want is to use `whereLike("name", "Pavel")`, which uses an SQL `LIKE` clause used for substring matching.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have one more question: can I create SORM-equivalent of SQL:
`WHERE s.name LIKE "Pavel" OR s.phone LIKE "12345"`
Sorry for syntax questions :)

Comment: Okay, from `sorm.Dsl` we have access to dsl-shortcuts for `sorm.Querier` functions so my filter now looks like `.where(("name" like filter) or ("phone" like filter))` as described in [documentation](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html).